# Sticky view with vertical scrolling using constraint layout or any other way in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

The red portion is wrap content and can be expanded, depends on how much data it contains. The green part/view always sticks between red and white. The screen is vertically scrollable.

THE attached XML code having scrollview and layout weight but it divides the screen into two parts from the middle, which is not as per the requirement.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_img_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/back_screen_color_list"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:contentPadding="20dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frm_club_img_wrapper"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_border_orange_bg">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_club"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/img_desc"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo_img_white" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <de.meinverein.app.view.RegularFontTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frm_club_img_wrapper"
                    android:text="Jetzt Profil\nverfolständigen"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/h1_lbl_size" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#0C0F12">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_club1"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dashboard_logo_width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_logo_height"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/img_desc"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo_img_white" />

                    <de.meinverein.app.view.BoldFontTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="MEINVEREIN"
                        android:textColor="@color/refs_btn"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_app_txt_size" />

                    <de.meinverein.app.view.BoldFontTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:text="Hallo Daniel,\ngerade nichts Neues!"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/list_view_item_txt_size_h1" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F6F6F6">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvAnimals"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvAdnimals"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/rvAnimals"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you show the layout code ?

Comment: Updated the code. Please review

Comment: I am still confused. do you have any example to show ? any app that implements such layout or any prototype ?

Comment: btw, why are you expanding red portion in scroll view ?. and what happen to your green view if you have enough data to expand your red portion to the bottom of the parent view ?

Comment: There can be multiple horizontal recyclerview in the red portion so it will extend accordingly. Green view should stick between the border of red and white.

Answer (score 1):

You can use constraint layout inside a nestedScrollView like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/redPortion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"           //Red Portion
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/green_sticky_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/redPortion"     //Green Sticky View
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/redPortion"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/whitePortion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"                        //White Portion
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/redPortion"
        />
    

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Use any layout you want for your red, white and green views.

I hope This helps.

Comment: It works. Does not need of NestedScrollView